# image not showing in webpage

Tags: html, image

EDIT: It is now working. Actually there were couple of problems. There WAS a special character which I failed to find out even after @Brady Liles mentioned. notice. and also the "topbanner" div class was creating problem.
Thanks everyone for helping me through this.

I'm having a strange problem. I don't know why this banner image is not showing up in browser.

the code used is

```
<div class="topbanner" style="margin: 5px auto; width: 468px;">
    <a href="https://www.internetmodeling.com/22472"><img src="./styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/im_468x60_1.gif" width="468" height="60" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
```

I've tried putting some other image their too, 728x90.jpg or 728x90.png
it doesn't show anyway.

But if I use the same image as the logo, then it works.

```
<div class="topbanner" style="margin: 5px auto; width: 468px;">
    <a href="https://www.internetmodeling.com/22472"><img src="./styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/Internet_modeling_forum.png" width="468" height="60" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
```

I'm out of idea. Can anyone please help me finding the cause of the issue?

Thanks in advance.

**The site in question is http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/
the banner code is right beneath the logo.**

EDIT: Things I've tried so far

```
src="http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/im_468x60_1.gif"
src="./styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/im_468x60_1.gif"
src="/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/im_468x60_1.gif"
src="./styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/728x90.png"
src="./styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/728x90.jpg"
```

You can check that the images are in there.
    http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/im_468x60_1.gif
http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/728x60.png
http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/728x60.jpg

Comment: I would advise you check, double-check, and triple check your directories and URLs.

Comment: Check if the image exists in the folder.

Comment: Thanks @Rorschach120 and sam2090 for quick response.
But the image is there! Check http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/im_468x60_1.gif

Comment: Also these images are there as well,

http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/728x90.jpg

http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/728x90.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/im_468x60_1.gif
```

It seems like your URL had a weird special character in it.. try copying and pasting this one in.

Do you have Adblock on??

Comment: Just changed the code to that. Not working. :(
I've tried absolute url too
`src="http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/im_468x60_1.gif"`

Comment: I'm getting a 404 when accessing that image.. it's not there.

Comment: I figured it out... the m was some type of special character.
Try coping and pasting this in now.
http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/im_468x60_1.gif (Updated Answer)

Comment: I really become hopefull that, that was the case.
But I don't think it is.
I've tried several other images, url format. But same thing happens.

See this two screenshots, taken from my notepad++
http://s21.postimg.org/4uo270w8n/code.jpg and http://s21.postimg.org/m98afatdj/hex.jpg

Comment: for which image are you getting 404? can you please try again?

Comment: No, why? What does this has to do with adblock?

Comment: I created a JS Fiddle of what you had and adblock blocked it for me.

Comment: Hmm. may be 468x60 in a img tag matches with some adblock filter.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my system:

```
<div class="topbanner" style="margin: 5px auto; width: 468px;">
    <img src="http://www.internetmodelingforum.com/styles/quarto_amazon_light/imageset/im_468x60_1.gif" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify which site?